# Make a rectangle button with text that link to a site url in shopify liquid

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I am trying to figure out how to make a rectangular button within shopify liquid code, which uses a mix of html and css. When clicking on the button, I want it to link to a website url. I tried using the code here but a square is not appearing, I also do not know where to put/how to implement the url link.

```css
.square {
    display: flex;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#8F0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="sqaure">
    colored square
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired styling does not apply because of a typo in your class name `class="sqaure"`. Additionally, if you wish that element to link somewhere, you will need to use an anchor tag, and supply the link in the `href` attribute, in the following example I used the liquid code that returns your own shop url:

```css
.square {
    display: flex;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#8F0000;
}
```

```html
<a class="square" href="{{ shop.url }}">
    colored square
</a>
```